# How to create a custom Slider control

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uislider

I need to make a slider like this.
It needs to stick to a line of text, and all texts need to be the same size no matter how long they are (one sentence could be a lot longer then another one)

[image: slider]

My approach right now is to create a custom `UIView` and calculate location of text and add `CATextLayer` in the correct places.

And handling pan/tap gestures my self.

Is there a simpler way to do this? is it possible to use `UISlider` for this? `UIlabels` instead of the `CATextLayers`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal `UISlider` with rotation to make it vertical `.transform` to rotate it. For example to make it vertical can use

```
mySlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

Then, change your `UISlider` using custom subclass, something like below.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    self.tintColor = .red
    self.maximumTrackTintColor = .red
}
```